# how to write a basic batch process to copy files from one location to another location on windows 7

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy, command

How do I write a basic batch process to copy files from one location to another location and give a limit or rule where I can enter the number of files that can be copied and from which file to which file?

Example: If I have 300 files I want to just copy from 50 to 250 files.

Comment: Generally Stack Overflow is not meant for "Write this code for me". Its for someone who attempted it, and is having issues and they post their code, and what they have tried and we help out. This is not meant as a code repository for how to write something. For that I recommend Google.

Answer (score 4):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"
SET "source=%cd%\*.bat"
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%i in (
 'xcopy /L /y "%source%" "%destdir%\" ^|findstr /n ":" '
 ) DO (
  IF %%i leq 12 ECHO XCOPY "%%j" "%destdir%\"
)
```

should do the job, echoing the first 12 copies to be performed, copying the batch files from the current directory to the destination.

The process relies on `:` in the source filename, so `%cd%` is used in preference to `.`